# List items in an unordered list are overlapping only in Internet Explorer, everything works fine in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, vue.js

I have created the following list item which works fine in chrome and every other browser that I have tried. It, however, does not work in IE.

[image: This first image is a link to the list working in Chrome]

[image: This is the image of the list being bunched up and overlapping in IE]

I have created this application using the vue framework and have had multiple issues with Internet Explorer that have been able to be solved but I have been unable to find anything where other people have had a similar issue to this. 
For some reason, once an item within the list has been selected the list then works as normal, but on the initial load of the page, the list is as shown in the images above. Also, the list is unable to scroll in IE until an item within the list has been selected.

[image: This is the list after an item has been selected and how I would like it to be displayed initially]

Here is the list being CSS.

```
ul{
    background-color: white;
    padding-top:10px !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 450px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And the code used for the scroll bar that works fine in other browsers.

```
.col-4, .col-8{
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
}

html{
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .list-group{
        margin-right: -16px;
    }
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Only IE still honors overflow rules on the html element. try changing

```
html{
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
to 
body{
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
```

To determine which Emulation mode IE11 is using in your development environment use the Emulation tab of the f12 dev tool.
If you are upgrading an old application to the newer framework, remove any presentation attributes (align, scroll, background etc) from the html tag.